# Android UI: Size 2 view?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

Good day everyone, currently i'm trying to make my first Android app, and then the first thing i realized, that idiotic XML UI designing.

I have this 2 view (button) and i'd like to make them so the first one fill the half of the parent (RelativeLayout) and the second one fills the other half of the parent...
My Code is:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Top1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Top2"
        android:text="top1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Top2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Top1"
        android:text="TOP2"/>
```

The problem, that i'm get this error:
"No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toLeftOf' with value '@id/Top2')."

It seems, that not even Android want to use XML.
Like an old C program where if a method is written below the call, it will give an error...

So i have 2 question:
1: How to solve this problem in the XML?
2: Or can i avoid this XML designing, and use code-like design like in C# ?

Comment: Have you tried the Android Studio's framework? In the most cases you don't even need to touch the XML code. Just drag, drop and resize.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can go about this and I provided you with two ways to have buttons aligned side by side.:

1. Use a LinearLayout with orientation set as horizontal

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/btn_container">

       <Button
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Left Button"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:id="@+id/btn_left" />

       <Button
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="Right Button"
           android:id="@+id/btn_right" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Use a RelativeLayout and an extra View to align your buttons.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <View
           android:id="@+id/strut"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_left"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignRight="@id/strut"
           android:text="Left Button" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_right"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@id/strut"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:text="Right Button" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: Thanks...
This would solve the first problem... The second one will be even harder in this piece of crap XML desginer...

Comment: It just takes some time getting used to designing with XML. Alternatively, you could do all the above in code but I'm not a fan of doing design work in code.

Comment: I like Code-designing way more, i think it gives me more advantages...
Mostly the "Compiler" type working not an "Interpreter" like...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `Top2` needs to be defined first in the XML before you can refer to it. That being said, if all you are doing is putting 2 buttons next to each other and have them fill the parent, you should consider using a `LinearLayout`. Order is important there, too: for horizontal orientation the children are laid out left to right, for vertical they are laid out top to bottom.

Comment: Soo... Is there a way, that i make a "Declaration field" in the XML, and then the organising ?
Something like in Pascal, the things get declared first and then to use them ?